# Init REFs in constructor in Oracle database object

Tags: oracle, object

I have a problem with initialization of REF values in Oracle. When trying to set them in constructor I get errors, no matter how I try it. Is there any way to init them on construction in situation like that?

```
CREATE TYPE tSomething AS OBJECT (
 Name Varchar(30)
);

CREATE TYPE tSomethingElse AS OBJECT (
 Something REF tSomething
);
```

Comment: Where are those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref is unique identifier of existing object. You have to create object table to get this unique identifier.

```
CREATE TYPE tSomething AS OBJECT (
 Name Varchar(30)
);


create table tSomething_table of tSomething;


CREATE TYPE tSomethingElse AS OBJECT (
 Something REF tSomething
);



declare 
 tSomethingElse_obj tSomethingElse; 
 tSomething_ref REF tSomething;
 tSomething_obj tSomething;
begin
 -- insert objects into tSomething_table
 insert into tSomething_table values('abc');
 insert into tSomething_table values('yyy');
 -- get ref one object. 
 select ref(p) into tSomething_ref  from tSomething_table p where p.name = 'abc';
 -- initialize tSomethingElse_obj; 
 tSomethingElse_obj := new tSomethingElse(tSomething_ref);

 -- extract get real tSomething object from ref
 select deref(tSomething_ref) into tSomething_obj  from dual;

end;
```